# Sum associated tables using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How does one sum all of the "total" columns in an association?

My SQL-fu sucks, so I would like to learn how to do so using Active Record for my rails 2.3.5 app (so no fancy syntax just yet please ;-) And I'm on MySQL.

Let's say I have:

```
Shop 

has_many :customers
has_many :transactions, :through => :customers
```

So normal stuff.

```
shop = Shop.first
shop.transactions
=> 100
```

Ok, all that background for the question:

**I want to SUM the `total` column in the transactions from the past year (Jan 1st 2010..Dec 31 2010) and display them by customer.**

Whilst I know how to group transactions and find with conditions, it's the sum part where my lack of SQL lets me down.

```
first = Date.new(2010, 01, 01)
last = Date.new(2010, 12, 31)

shop.transactions(:conditions => {:created_at => first..last}, :group => :customer_id, :include => sum(:total))
```

I just took a stab, am i on the right track?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
shop.transactions.sum(:total, :conditions => {:created_at => first..last}, :group => :customer_id)
```

This looks like an easier way. I now know that sum can take AR attributes too. cool.

Answer (score 0):

Look into collect methods.

You can do things like:

```
transactions = Shop.transactions
total = 0
sum = transactions.collect{|i| total+=i.transaction.amount}
```

Replace amount with your property that contains the amount of the transaction.

You could also use .sum

```
sum = transactions.to_a.sum(&:amount)
```

Comment: also, I'd use inject if i was going to do that.  The old me would have, but I'm trying to use the database for what it's good 'at'.